# What is the English word for a 'spaghetti harvest'?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Spaghetti, traditionally, an Italian crop is now being widely grown in Britain. Can anyone say what the harvest should be called, perhaps based on the Italian.

Comment: A [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXmaS1ZzpA8) might make things clearer, maybe :)

Comment: @oerkelens - great link! good chuckles.

Comment: There's no word for it in English other than the obvious 'spaghetti harvest'. Otherwise you're asking for a (opinion based) judgement on a neologism/borrowing.

Comment: It is more like a 'spaghetti hunt'.  Harvest is for things that are collected but **don't fight back**.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is a trolling exercise. The BBC film was an April Fool's joke in the early 1960s.

Answer (score 5):

In certain parts of Italy, it's referred to as *il raccolto di spaghetti* (or *il raccolto* for short), while in others (esp. in more southerly regions) call it *i giorni maccheroni abbondanti* or **gimadanti**.

Though I've never been during those weeks, it looks like fun.

[image: An image in three parts, with the top half depicting a smiling woman looking at a serving fork full of spaghetti-like pasta. Underneath, an image of three people: two women and a man appear to be harvesting spaghetti from trees. One woman is on a ladder. The man is holding a large round flat basket. The last image is of a woman apparently collecting spaghetti from a plant.]

Answer (score 0):

Why not 'spaghetti harvest'? You have a 'corn harvest' or a 'wine harvest', so a 'spaghetti harvest' seems perfectly acceptable and understandable.

As oerkelens' [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXmaS1ZzpA8) shows, it was even used by the BBC in 1957. There's no greater bastion of Britishness than the beeb.